# Android Studio 2.1 - debugging very slow in device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am newly to android studio.. i trying to run my project in mobile. Activity getting launch in mobile after 5 mins and then another 5 mins application getting open with  fully blank screen . At last application opens successfully.  For every lauch i am facing the issues same. Please help to fix this issue
[image]
My laptop process speed is good only. Its 8 gb ram.

Comment: Is your instant run is on?

Comment: This was an issue reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206698).

Comment: yes. so i need back to version 1.5 ?